# Glom won't launch on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, launcher

I'm quite new to linux and I discovered Glom in the App Manager of Ubuntu 16.04.

I like their idea of keeping data and UI separated: I'd be less stressed about accessing my data in a "what if" scenario.

However it seems unable to launch.
Apparently, some people experienced it too.

Would anyone know why ?

(Practically, the icon blinks as usual in the launcher, then it stops at some point and nothing happened).

Best regards

---

Edit:

When running Glom from terminal :

> glom: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libboost_python-py34.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Comment: Try running it in terminal so you can see the error messages. Please [edit] and include it in its entirety (Obs.: Open Terminal with CTRL+ALT+T or searching it in the dash and simply type `glom` and enter).

Comment: Ok, just editted the post :-)

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glom/+bug/1573801